# Node moving from Point to Point by touch in SpriteKit Sene

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I have a SKNode and I Want to move this node from point (10,10) TO (10,100) by touch .. (and to make this node moving between this two points only )not on the all scene like i have right now in the touch moved method
Then .Can I Create a path for my node between these points,If I Can What You Suggest Me To Use .

Thanks

```
-(void)touchesMoved : (NSSet *)touches withEvent : (UIEvent *) event{

[_Player runAction:[SKAction moveTo:[[touches anyObject]locationInNode:self]duration:0.01];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can. You have to create a path, like this:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 0, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 100, 100);
```

then use this method

```
SKAction *followline = [SKAction followPath:path asOffset:YES orientToPath:NO duration:3.0];
[_Player runAction:followline];
```